# Why this code is not awaiting even though i used await asyncio.await()?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to use websocket in my discord bot. This code was in separated process, and I want to unify processes. discord.py uses websocket, so I need to use threading. To send message to channels I need to await coroutine. time.sleep(), await asyncio.sleep(), none of them is working.

```py
@app.event
async def on_ready():
    print("로그인 정보>")
    print(app.user.name)
    print(app.user.id)
    print("=============")

    await app.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="도움말을 받으려면 st!help ", type=1))

    async def on_message_live(ws, message):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
        print(message)
        message = json.loads(message)
        if message["Type"] == 'UsersOnline':
            return
        if message["Type"] == 'LogOff':
            return
        if message["Type"] == 'LogOn':
            return
        gameid = list(message['Apps'].keys())[0]
        messageStr = "{} #{} - Apps: {} ({})".format(message['Type'], message['ChangeNumber'], message['Apps'][gameid],
                                                     gameid)
        if message['Packages'] != {}:
            packageid = list(message['Packages'].keys())[0]
            messageStr += ' - Packages: {} ({})'.format(message['Packages'][packageid], packageid);
        print(messageStr)
        for channel in realtimeList:
            app.send_message(app.get_channel(channel.id), messageStr)

    def on_error_live(ws, error):
        print(error)

    def on_close_live(ws):
        print("### closed ###")

    def on_open_live(ws):
        pass

    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://steamdb.info/api/realtime/",
                                 on_message=on_message_live,
                                 on_error=on_error_live,
                                 on_close=on_close_live)
    ws.on_open = on_open_live
    wst = threading.Thread(target=ws.run_forever)
    wst.daemon = True
    wst.start()
```

Please ignore every shitty code.

I want to send message to channels. Without await, I can't send message.

Comment: ```D:\CodingData\SteamBot\env\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py:345: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_message_live' was never awaited
  callback(self, *args)```
This is the error I received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From websocket_client project description: https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/#description

All APIs are the synchronous functions.

You are passing async function to an API that was designed to work with synchronous functions, thus it never awaits the handlers you pass to it. The fact that you await something in the handler does not mean that the handler is awaited.